# ASP.Net Core web api 404 not found

Tags: asp.net-core

I create a Web Api in asp.net core this the content of Api:

```
namespace CPTestApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EnergyController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly CP_FinalContext _context;

        public EnergyController(CP_FinalContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Energy")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TblEnergyDetail>>> TblEnergyDetail()
        {
            return await _context.TblEnergyDetails.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

So when I try to call the Energy by browser or Postman, by this url https://localhost:(port)/api/Energy, it gets me 404 error, what is the problem?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web API Basic Route is

```
api/Energy
```

for routing to `Energy` method you should route the request to

```
 api/Energy/Energy
```